# How to create an ASP.NET Core WebAPI project with F# in Rider?

Tags: f#, project, rider

I am using rider but some reasons I can't see any option to create web-related projects with F#.

I even installed the Girafe template but I still don't see anything in the project creation panel.

is there anything I can do to projec templates with F# in Rider?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not have Rider but I took a look at how they support it. The dotnet templates seem to be tied to the sdk version that was used to install them. If Rider is using a different version than the command line, it would explain the behavior. Just an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Rider does not support these web templates. I mean we have disabled them intentionally in the Rider's source code ~ 2 years ago:

```
// HACK: Do not show F# web templates
if (info.GroupIdentity.StartsWith("Microsoft.Web") && info.GetTagValue(LanguageGroupProvider.LanguageTag) == "F#") continue;
```

In 2019.2 (the next release) we will enable them because for know all known issues with F# and web were fixed. We just forgot to enable templates.

I can suggest to use `dotnet` command line for now. Sorry for inconvenience.